# convert object to DocumentDb Document in .Net Core

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.0, document-database

I have the following code which takes in a object of type employee based on it's model, I want to convert this to a DocumentDB Document then post to the database.
How would I do the conversion?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody]Employee employee)
        {
            using (_logger.BeginScope("Post employee"))
            {
                try
                {
                    // convert employee to Document??
                    await _documentDbRepository.CreateItemsAsync(document);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the signature for `CreateItemsAsync` explicitly require you to pass in a `Document`? This appears to be some custom abstraction you have over the actual DocumentClient which is capable of taking just about any `object` and inserting it into Cosmos using default JSON serialization

Comment: The CreateItemsAsync does for the moment require a Document, so you mean it can accept in a type 'object' and this would work whether it's a Document or a custom object based on a model?

Comment: What is `_documentDbRepository`? It sounds like a custom layer that you have built on top. If it's hard coded for Document then you're going to have to respect that t the moment. The regular DocumentClient can accept any objects, not just Documents.

Comment: changed it to accept in an object, so as long as I create a new id guid for each thing being passed in it works fine.  If you want to put your original comment as an answer i'll accept, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using a custom layer over top of the regular Cosmos libraries which is hard coded to only accept a `Document`. The libraries supplied by Microsoft are capable of inserting any generic object and will use default JSON serialization to turn it into a Document for you at insert time. Changing the signature on your custom repository to accept `Object` instead of `Document` should get you unblocked.